# Jquery fullcalendar - how to make current month (days) unselectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a SharePoint-hosted app in SharePoint. Basicaly it is a time planning app. I used a jquery calendar plugin (fullcalendar). My question is I have a "lock" button. When user clicks the button it should make the calendar days unselectable (only the days in the current month). Appreciate if someone can help me with it.

```
I was trying like this.

function LockMonth() {
    var schedulecCalendar = $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: false,

    });
}
```

When I run the app I can click on the calendar day and add event from the textbox to the calendar. But once I click on "lock" button then it should make the calendar unselectable. But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have just put up a fiddle for you,[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MTdn/349/) hope that helps

SCRIPT

```
 $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar(
            {
             header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },

             dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) { 
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    var isLocked=document.getElementById("locked")
                    var currMonth = getCurrentDisplayedMonth()
                    var blockedMonths = getMonthsBlockedByUserFromList();   
                    alert($.inArray(currMonth,blockedMonths))
                    if ($.inArray(currMonth,blockedMonths) != -1) {
                       alert("You cannot book on this day!");   
                         return 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Excellent choice! We can book today..");    
                     }   
                 },      

             events: [
                        {
                            title  : 'event2',
                            start  : '2011-03-10',
                            end    : '2011-05-5'
                        }
                    ]
         }); 


$('#btnlocked').click(function(){
    //add the month to blocked list 
 var isLocked=document.getElementById("locked")
 if(isLocked.value=="false") {   
     isLocked.value=true;
    $('#btnlocked').val("Unlock Month")
         alert('Month locked')
    }
  else{
     isLocked.value=false;
    $('#btnlocked').val("Lock Month")
         alert('Month unlocked')
    }
});

function getMonthsBlockedByUserFromList(){
  //retrieve all months for the year blocked by respective user from SP list
  // return array of months blocked(0= Jan,1=Feb...4=May and so on) 
  //suppose follwing months are blocked
    var monthsBlockedByXyz= [0,4,5,6];
     return monthsBlockedByXyz;
}

function getCurrentDisplayedMonth(){
  var date = $("#mycalendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
  var month_int = date.getMonth();
    return month_int;
  //you now have the visible month as an integer from 0-11
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="locked" value="false"/>
<input type="button" id="btnlocked" value="Lock month"/>
<div id="mycalendar"> Calendar </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code I really appreciate it. It worked for only the current month but I want to lock some specific month as well like past month februari or future month october. How can I lock independently different months?

Comment: yes i had made it for current month, can you tell me how you determine which month to blocks so that i would modify the code

Comment: Once the user lock the current month, notification will be sent to the admin and the user will no longer make any change in the calendar unless the admin gives him the right to do so.
This is monthly activity and the user should be able to lock(submit) for subsequent months as well.

Comment: Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: I just have a doubt where do you plan to save/store the data when xyz month is been locked by a particular user.

Comment: When the user adds an event it will be saved in a SharePoint list. But when the user locks the month with all the events in that particular month  then it will be saved in a new SharePoint list that only is available for the admin.

Comment: I have updated the code above you can follow comments and implement the logic as per requirement

Comment: The above code fetches the blocked months. I am also curious about how the user can block any months.

Comment: To insert you need create an item in the list after checking if the same Year and Month for that particular exists within list

Comment: Okey thank you, but as I can see the lock button it does not have blocking code, instead its just changes the value of the button.

Comment: Yes i have left it unchanged as i don't know what method you use to insert data, your insert logic should go there in Click function, give it a try you can't expect me to write a code without knowing your site structure, i just gave you the a generic logic use it as per your needs

Comment: Okey I understand you now. Thank you alot! I will insert logic and give it a try.